# Moving WordPress Directory (same domain) - GUID issue?

Tags: guids

I have a WordPress installation on a directory within my domain. So, it is like this:

```
www.example.com/blog/
WordPress is placed in /blog/
```

I'd like to move the WordPress installation Blog Posts back to the root level. When I exported the XML file I noticed that each blog post had this GUID reference:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://example.com/blog/?p=1275</guid>
>> notice the /blog/ in the URL <<
```

So, my question is - if I import the XML file into a fresh WordPress install at the root level, wont all the links be broken?

Should I change all the GUID links? My understanding is that the GUID URL should be left alone even if the domain path has changed.

Answer (score 2):

GUIDs are not URLs, they are unique identifiers that happen to look like URLs. It was, in my opinion, a poor design choice to make them URLs, because it causes a lot of confusion.

They are essentially a way to establish the "global uniqueness" of a post, and you should not change these for content that has already been published.

The GUID is not involved in generating permalinks or resolving incoming requests, so nothing will be broken as long as the API is used correctly, however, I have seen plugin and theme authors use GUIDs as though they were URLs, so watch out for third-party code.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. But aren't these GUID referencing something that isn't there anymore? The full path of the GUID will always be broken because I am moving directory down a level...?

Comment: OK I guess the key thing is that the GUID is an ID that is the original referencer for the content - so it's all good to ignore the legacy nature of it when moving to a new location.